# Connect Silverlight to Office 365 / "Sharepoint 2010 online"

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, ms-office, office365

I have a SilverLight application (silverlight 3) running on Microsoft Office 365 (beta). Getting the app into 365 is no problem, but I found no way to connect to the SharePoint contents, e.g. listitems...

Some ideas?

Comment: "connect" means I want to read items out of sharepoint lists and manipulate / write them (via silverlight)

Comment: Can this be of any help ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615590.aspx#Y526

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Client Side Object Model.

[MSDN - Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx)